# python struct pack with space padding

Tags: python, struct, pack

I need to create/send binary data in python using a given protocol.
The protocol calls for fixed width fields , with space padding thrown in.
Using python's struct.pack, the only thing I can think of is, calculating the space padding and adding it in myself.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: space padding as in the space character or space padding as in padding with 0 bytes?

Answer (score 8):

struct has a [placeholder](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-strings) (`x`) for a padding byte you can use:

```
 # pack 2 16 bit values plus one pad byte
 from struct import pack
 packedStrWithOneBytePad = pack("hhx", 1000, 2000)
```

Comment: Nothing in the documentation indicates, that you can specify what the pad should be.. and I think I read that it is by default null. Though I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @Pradyot yeah I doubt you can configure the pad. You might just need to fill the pad yourself with a normal byte and specify what character you want to use.

Comment: Ok. thanks. Just wanted to make sure , that was the only way.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, at all.

Answer (score 1):

For a 64bit based CPU, use '0l' to align the bytes with a repeat count of zero.

Example: 
`bytes = struct.pack('???0l',1,2,3)` 
`print(len(bytes)) // will print 8`